# `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync

Tags: reactjs, npm, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am having this issue when my react app runs the GitHub actions as CI for builds.

> npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

[image: For more context on the error, here is a full log of the error screenshot, in case there is any details that would be helpful.]

I added this step to my build script:

```
- name: Update package-lock.json
        run: |
          cd my-app
          rm package-lock.json
          npm install
```

Here is my complete build script:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: 'Create env file'
        run: |
          cd my-app
          echo "${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}" > .env
      - name: Update package-lock.json
        run: |
          cd my-app
          rm package-lock.json
          npm install
      - run: (cd my-app && npm ci)
      - run: (cd my-app && npm run build)
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_HELLO_WORLD_12345 }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: hello-world-12345
          entrypoint: "./my-app"

      - name: Send Discord notification on success
        if: ${{ success() }}
        run: curl -s -X POST "${{ secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK }}" -d "content= Firebase Hosting Merge Successful"

      - name: Send Discord notification on failure
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: curl -s -X POST "${{ secrets.DISCORD_WEBHOOK }}" -d "content= Firebase Hosting Merge Failed"
```

Comment: how is typescript dependency is added in your package.json?

Comment: Your workflow doesn't make a lot of sense. Why install the dependencies twice? If you're willing to do that, what's the point of using `ci`? Why _is_ your lockfile out of sync? Why do you keep cd-ing instead of setting the working directory?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure it out. This is how I solved the issue in my question above:

```
cd my-app
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
```

I got an error about permission when I ran the command
`npm cache clean --force`, I then did this to resolve that error `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/me/.npm"` and after that, I:

```
npm install
```

After completing these steps, I committed the changes to my repository and pushed them to trigger the GitHub Actions workflow, which resolved the error.

Comment: kinda crazy that we have to do this

Answer (score 2):

Deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, and npm cache did NOT work for me

### Here's how I fixed it.

1. Run `npm config set legacy-peer-deps false` in terminal
2. Delete functions/node_modules, functions/package-lock.json
3. Delete the Firebase functions
4. Run `firebase deploy --only functions`

Watch it succeed this time.

See the reference where I discovered this - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6216

Comment: thanks! I additionally had to delete the ~/.npm directory. for reference: npm 10.4.0, next 14.1.0, firebase-tools 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- npm config set legacy-peer-deps false
- rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json // inside functions folder
- npm cache clean --force
- npm i
- firebase deploy --only functions

Note to myself: I ran `firebase deploy --only functions:app` because I had a named function called 'app'

Comment: This is nice! Thanks for sharing what worked for you.